# Spring boot restful webservice not working on localhost

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have created a simple webservice with spring boot and when I try to test it in intelliJ i got the message in image below.

[image: Web service request]

This is my controller

```
@RestController
public class RoomController {
    @Autowired
    private RoomRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/rooms", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    List<Room> findAll(@RequestParam(required=false) String roomNumber){
       List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
        if(null==roomNumber){
            Iterable<Room> results = this.repository.findAll();
            results.forEach(room-> {rooms.add(room);});
        }else{
            Room room = this.repository.findByNumber(roomNumber);
            if(null!=room) {
                rooms.add(room);
            }
        }
        return rooms;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly share the stack trace.

Comment: Not sure why a DNS lookup would fail on localhost. Try replace it with 127.0.0.1

Comment: 504. Doesn't look like springboot's fault. Try "http://localhost:8080/rooms" in a few different browsers. If that works, could be a dodgy proxy set up in the rest client you're using?

Comment: The path should be `/rooms` not `rooms`.

Comment: do you have a proxy configured on port 8080? Does you spring boot application start without an error?

Comment: @AshishLohia which stack trace? #Spoon It Restful webservice client embaded with intelliJ provide automatically localhost:8080/rooms. #Deinum the path is correct. Maybe I should send screenshot when running to view the url generated by the client.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Yes I have proxy settings configured in settings.xml. `<proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>myproxy</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>host</host>
            <port>port</port>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pass</password>
            <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>`